# latexmk drops into pdfTex shell or something

Tags: pdftex, latexmk

I keep on reading articles on how to use latexmk, but when I try, the command never just exits. It always drops me into some kind of shell like this

```
$ latexmk -pdf latex-preview.tex 
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 5 February 2015, version: 4.43a.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Non-existent destination files:
      'latex-preview.pdf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "latex-preview.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./latex-preview.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
)
*
```

It never seems to produce any pdf output. The same happens when I use pdflatex.

Comment: Since it also happens with `pdflatex`, the issue is probably with your TeX document. Can you create a minimal example of your document that reproduces the problem?
(Usually, when I have this issue, it means I forgot `\end{document}`, but it can happen for other reasons.)

Comment: @ArunDebray Yes, that was the problem. I forgot to save the document so it was empty. An error code indicating that there was no `\end` would have been more useful, though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this happend when there is no `\end{document}` in the `.tex` file.

In my case, the file was just empty as I forgot to save it.